# How to add views to UIWebVIew? like this image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I wonder how some apps do this great affect, i've trying to accomplish this but without much success.

the idea is to add views like textview or label to a webview or to scollview so that it appears with gray background and can be scrolled, the below image describes the intended goal :

[image]
I would be very much appreciated if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code and just background color your UIView.Hope It will helps you.

```
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

Comment: Doesn't work, i want the textview ,labels..etc to be able to scroll with the webview not independent or fixed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a pure HTML/javascript/CSS solution, not a native UIVIew laid on top of the UIWebView

CSS like this creates an initially invisible box, 400px wide, 120px from top, white background, bordered:

```
.floater
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    z-index: 200;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: solid 2px #b0b0b0; 
    border-left: solid 2px #b0b0b0; 
    border-bottom: solid 2px black; 
    border-right: solid 2px black; 
}
```

Use this class="floater" on your label, div, whatever.

You can then use the display style to hide/unhide it via javascript.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your content to scroll within the webView, You have to add the view as a subview of the first subview of the webview.

The scrollview is the first subview of the webview

```
 [[[webview subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:imageview];
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - ny views scroll with the web view, but they are placed somehwere within the web content, not below it.

Comment: By the way, since iOS 5, you can use ```[webView scrollView]```. Not that it changes anything in this case, but...